# running php code to send email

Tags: php, email, ubuntu

hi i need some help i can already send mail through command line with this

```
cat sample_email.txt | msmtp --debug -a gmail bob@gmail.com
```

but when i try in php iam not recieving any email

here is my code:

```
<?php
if(mail("receipient@domain.com","A Subject Here","Hi there,\nThis email was sent using PHP's mail function."))
print "Email successfully sent";
else
print "An error occured";
?>
```

can somoene have a solution on this iam not getting any errors it prints "Email sent successfully" but iam not recieving any.

Comment: have you checked your spam ?

Comment: Some ISPs may also block port 25 in order to prevent spam, so make sure that this is not the case.